# Regex to capture multilines from specific expression until first blank line in Perl

Tags: regex, perl

i have this file and i would like to match everything between #sent_id=\d+ and blank line.
Here is my file :

```
# newdoc
# newpar
# sent_id = 1
# text = 2019, un bon cru pour les amateurs de technologie.
1   2019    2019    NUM _   _   5   nummod  _   SpaceAfter=No
2   ,   ,   PUNCT   _   _   1   punct   _   _
3   un  un  DET _   Definite=Ind|Gender=Masc|Number=Sing|PronType=Art   5   det _   _
4   bon bon ADJ _   Gender=Masc|Number=Sing 5   amod    _   _
5   cru cru NOUN    _   Gender=Masc|Number=Sing 0   root    _   _
6   pour    pour    ADP _   _   8   case    _   _
7   les le  DET _   Definite=Def|Gender=Masc|Number=Plur|PronType=Art   8   det _   _
8   amateurs    amateur NOUN    _   Gender=Masc|Number=Plur 5   nmod    _   _
9   de  de  ADP _   _   10  case    _   _
10  technologie technologie NOUN    _   Gender=Fem|Number=Sing  8   nmod    _   SpaceAfter=No
11  .   .   PUNCT   _   _   5   punct   _   SpacesAfter=\n

# sent_id = 2
# text = L’année a été généreuse en innovations prometteuses. Voici les six tendances qui pourraient bousculer notre paysage technologique.
1   L’  L’  PROPN   _   _   5   nsubj   _   SpaceAfter=No
2   année   année   NOUN    _   Gender=Fem|Number=Sing  1   nmod    _   _
3   a   avoir   AUX _   Mood=Ind|Number=Sing|Person=3|Tense=Pres|VerbForm=Fin   5   aux:tense   _   _
4   été être    AUX _   Gender=Masc|Number=Sing|Tense=Past|VerbForm=Part    5   cop _   _
5   généreuse   généreux    ADJ _   Gender=Fem|Number=Sing  0   root    _   _
6   en  en  ADP _   _   7   case    _   _
7   innovations innovation  NOUN    _   Gender=Fem|Number=Plur  5   obl _   _
8   prometteuses    prometteur  ADJ _   Gender=Fem|Number=Plur  7   amod    _   SpaceAfter=No
9   .   .   PUNCT   _   _   10  punct   _   _
10  Voici   voici   VERB    _   _   5   parataxis   _   _
11  les le  DET _   Definite=Def|Gender=Fem|Number=Plur|PronType=Art    13  det _   _
12  six six NUM _   _   13  nummod  _   _
13  tendances   tendance    NOUN    _   Gender=Fem|Number=Plur  10  obj _   _
14  qui qui PRON    _   PronType=Rel    15  nsubj   _   _
15  pourraient  pouvoir VERB    _   Mood=Cnd|Number=Plur|Person=3|Tense=Pres|VerbForm=Fin   13  acl:relcl   _   _
16  bousculer   bousculer   VERB    _   VerbForm=Inf    15  xcomp   _   _
17  notre   son DET _   Gender=Masc|Number=Sing|Poss=Yes|PronType=Prs   18  det _   _
18  paysage paysage NOUN    _   Gender=Masc|Number=Sing 16  obj _   _
19  technologique   technologique   ADJ _   Gender=Masc|Number=Sing 18  amod    _   SpaceAfter=No
20  .   .   PUNCT   _   _   5   punct   _   SpacesAfter=\n

# sent_id = 3
# text = A Hongkong, des centaines d’arrestations lors d’affrontements, une situation qui semble « désespérée ».
1   A   à   ADP _   _   2   case    _   _
2   Hongkong    Hongkong    PROPN   _   _   0   root    _   SpaceAfter=No
3   ,   ,   PUNCT   _   _   2   punct   _   _
4-5 des _   _   _   _   _   _   _   _
4   de  de  ADP _   _   6   case    _   _
5   les le  DET _   Definite=Def|Gender=Fem|Number=Plur|PronType=Art    6   det _   _
6   centaines   centaine    NOUN    _   Gender=Fem|Number=Plur  2   nmod    _   _
7   d’  d’  PROPN   _   _   6   appos   _   SpaceAfter=No
8   arrestations    arrestation NOUN    _   Gender=Fem|Number=Plur  7   flat:name   _   _
9   lors    lors    ADV _   _   10  case    _   _
10  d’  d’  PROPN   _   _   6   nmod    _   SpaceAfter=No
11  affrontements   affrontement    NOUN    _   Gender=Masc|Number=Plur 10  flat:name   _   SpaceAfter=No
12  ,   ,   PUNCT   _   _   14  punct   _   _
13  une un  DET _   Definite=Ind|Gender=Fem|Number=Sing|PronType=Art    14  det _   _
14  situation   situation   NOUN    _   Gender=Fem|Number=Sing  10  appos   _   _
15  qui qui PRON    _   PronType=Rel    16  nsubj   _   _
16  semble  sembler VERB    _   Mood=Ind|Number=Sing|Person=3|Tense=Pres|VerbForm=Fin   14  acl:relcl   _   _
17  «   «   PUNCT   _   _   18  punct   _   SpacesAfter= 
18  désespérée  désespéré   ADJ _   Gender=Fem|Number=Sing  16  xcomp   _   SpacesAfter= 
19  »   »   PUNCT   _   _   18  punct   _   SpaceAfter=No
20  .   .   PUNCT   _   _   10  punct   _   SpacesAfter=\n

# sent_id = 4
# text = Des dizaines de milliers de personnes ont défilé dans la mégapole. « C’est triste que nos revendications de 2019 doivent être reportées à 2020 », a souligné un des organisateurs.
1-2 Des _   _   _   _   _   _   _   _
1   De  de  ADP _   _   3   case    _   _
2   les le  DET _   Definite=Def|Gender=Fem|Number=Plur|PronType=Art    3   det _   _
3   dizaines    dizaine NOUN    _   Gender=Fem|Number=Plur  9   nsubj   _   _
4   de  de  ADP _   _   5   case    _   _
5   milliers    millier NOUN    _   Gender=Masc|Number=Plur 3   nmod    _   _
6   de  de  ADP _   _   7   case    _   _
7   personnes   personne    NOUN    _   Gender=Fem|Number=Plur  5   nmod    _   _
8   ont avoir   AUX _   Mood=Ind|Number=Plur|Person=3|Tense=Pres|VerbForm=Fin   9   aux:tense   _   _
9   défilé  défiler VERB    _   Gender=Masc|Number=Sing|Tense=Past|VerbForm=Part    31  ccomp   _   _
10  dans    dans    ADP _   _   12  case    _   _
11  la  le  DET _   Definite=Def|Gender=Fem|Number=Sing|PronType=Art    12  det _   _
12  mégapole    mégapole    NOUN    _   Gender=Fem|Number=Sing  9   obl:arg _   SpaceAfter=No
13  .   .   PUNCT   _   _   17  punct   _   _
14  «   «   PUNCT   _   _   17  punct   _   SpacesAfter= 
15  C’  C’  PROPN   _   _   17  nsubj   _   SpaceAfter=No
16  est être    AUX _   Mood=Ind|Number=Sing|Person=3|Tense=Pres|VerbForm=Fin   17  cop _   _
17  triste  triste  ADJ _   Gender=Masc|Number=Sing 9   xcomp   _   _
18  que que SCONJ   _   _   23  mark    _   _
19  nos son DET _   Gender=Fem|Number=Plur|Poss=Yes|PronType=Prs    20  det _   _
20  revendications  revendication   NOUN    _   Gender=Fem|Number=Plur  23  nsubj   _   _
21  de  de  ADP _   _   22  case    _   _
22  2019    2019    NUM _   _   20  nmod    _   _
23  doivent devoir  VERB    _   Mood=Ind|Number=Plur|Person=3|Tense=Pres|VerbForm=Fin   17  ccomp   _   _
24  être    être    AUX _   VerbForm=Inf    25  aux:pass    _   _
25  reportées   reporter    VERB    _   Gender=Fem|Number=Plur|Tense=Past|VerbForm=Part 23  xcomp   _   _
26  à   à   ADP _   _   27  case    _   _
27  2020    2020    NUM _   _   25  obl:arg _   SpacesAfter= 
28  »   »   PUNCT   _   _   17  punct   _   SpaceAfter=No
29  ,   ,   PUNCT   _   _   9   punct   _   _
30  a   avoir   AUX _   Mood=Ind|Number=Sing|Person=3|Tense=Pres|VerbForm=Fin   31  aux:tense   _   _
31  souligné    souligner   VERB    _   Gender=Masc|Number=Sing|Tense=Past|VerbForm=Part    0   root    _   _
32  un  un  PRON    _   Gender=Masc|Number=Sing 31  nsubj   _   _
33-34   des _   _   _   _   _   _   _   _
33  de  de  ADP _   _   35  case    _   _
34  les le  DET _   Definite=Def|Gender=Masc|Number=Plur|PronType=Art   35  det _   _
35  organisateurs   organisateur    NOUN    _   Gender=Masc|Number=Plur 32  nmod    _   SpaceAfter=No
36  .   .   PUNCT   _   _   31  punct   _   SpacesAfter=\n
```

I would like to capture everything between `#sent_id` and a new `#sent_id`.

I've tried this but it matches all the file.

```
sub extract_dependancies{

    open my $fh, "<:encoding(utf-8)", shift or die "$!\n";
    undef $/;
    my $file = <$fh>;
   # sent_id to blank line
    while($file =~ /^#\ssent.+\d+(.+)^$/msg){
        my $sentence = $1;
        #next if $sentence !~ /d+\tobj/;
    }
}
```

The scalar sentence retrieve all the file. I would like to have sentence by sentence. sentence should be contain the content between two # sent_id like this.

```
# text = 2019, un bon cru pour les amateurs de technologie.
1   2019    2019    NUM _   _   5   nummod  _   SpaceAfter=No
2   ,   ,   PUNCT   _   _   1   punct   _   _
3   un  un  DET _   Definite=Ind|Gender=Masc|Number=Sing|PronType=Art   5   det _   _
4   bon bon ADJ _   Gender=Masc|Number=Sing 5   amod    _   _
5   cru cru NOUN    _   Gender=Masc|Number=Sing 0   root    _   _
6   pour    pour    ADP _   _   8   case    _   _
7   les le  DET _   Definite=Def|Gender=Masc|Number=Plur|PronType=Art   8   det _   _
8   amateurs    amateur NOUN    _   Gender=Masc|Number=Plur 5   nmod    _   _
9   de  de  ADP _   _   10  case    _   _
10  technologie technologie NOUN    _   Gender=Fem|Number=Sing  8   nmod    _   SpaceAfter=No
11  .   .   PUNCT   _   _   5   punct   _   SpacesAfter=\n
```

for the first sentence and so forth. But either I capture all the file or nothing at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way: read the file in chunks of text between empty lines.

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

die "Usage: $0 file\n" if not @ARGV;

my @sentences;

# First pass lines until the first  "# sent_id =..." (and that one)
while (<>) { last if /^\s*#\s*sent_id/ }

local $/ = "\n\n";  # read in blocks of up to an empty line

while (<>) {
    # Remove the leading line "# sent_id =...", return the rest
    push @sentences, s{ ^ \#\s* sent_id\s* = \s*[0-9]+ .*?\n }{}xr;
}

say for @sentences;
```

The first `while <>` is used to get to and pass the first `sent_id` line. Then the next `while (<>)` starts from where the first one stopped, and reads the file by blocks delimited by an empty line.

The first line in each block, with `sent_id`, is matched and removed, while the rest is returned (by the ["non-destructive"](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut#Search-and-replace) `/r` modifier) and added to the array.

This retains the trailing empty line in each "sentence," easily removed if need be.

I read the file using the magical ["null filehandle" `<>`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop#I/O-Operators) and do everything in the main program for simplicity, but please do put it in a nice subroutine as in the question.  Then it can return a reference to `@sentences`.

Note the [`local`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/local), which in a short program like above doesn't matter but is crucial to use in general; with it the global variable on which it is applied (here `$/`) is restored upon leaving the scope. The code in the question changes the global [`$/` variable](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar#$/) for all code in the interpreter.

---

Or use regex to parse the file, as asked for and attempted.

One way: iterate using the `# sent_id = ...` lines as token

```
use warnings;
use strict; 
use feature 'say';

die "Usage: $0 file\n" if not @ARGV;

my $content = do { local $/; <> };

my @sentences;

while ( $content =~ / \#\s* sent_id \s*=\s* [0-9]+ .*? \n /gx ) {
    push @sentences, $content =~ /\G (.*?) (?:\n\n|$)/sx;
    #say "pos = ", pos $content;
}

say for @sentences;
```

The `\G` anchors to where the previous match with `/g` modifier left off.  So the pattern with it (in the `push...` line) starts matching from after what the pattern in the `while` condition matched, so it matches everything from after the previous `# sent_id...` line to the next empty line.

Please see docs for how the combination of `/g` and `\G` works and can be used, for example in ["Global Matching" in perlretut](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut#Global-matching)

Or, get everything in one shot

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

die "Usage: $0 file\n" if not @ARGV;

my $content = do { local $/; <> };

my @sentences = 
    $content =~ / \#\s*sent_id\s*=\s*[0-9]+ .*?\n (.+?) (?:\n\n|$) /gsx;

say for @sentences;
```

This is in my opinion the trickiest and least robust solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -ne '$f=0 if /sent_id/; print "$_" if $f; $f=1 if /sent_id/' french.in > french.out
```

This one-liner captures everything between one `#sent_id` and the next `#sent_id`.

How does it work:

```
perl -MO=Deparse -ne '$f=0 if /sent_id/; print "$_" if $f; $f=1 if /sent_id/' french.in

LINE: while (defined($_ = readline ARGV)) {
    $f = 0 if /sent_id/;
    print "$_" if $f;
    $f = 1 if /sent_id/;
}
```

While the first line is being processed, the tag `#sent_id = 1` is matched and switches `$f` into the false state: `$f=0 if /sent_id/;`

The next statement, `print "$_" if $f` is therefore not executed.

Then, while the first line is still being processed, the tag `#sent_id = 1` is matched again and switches `$f` into the true state: `$f=1 if /sent_id/;`

The `while` loop enters the next iteration and moves to the next line: `"# text = 2019, un bon cru pour les amateurs de technologie."`

Since `$f` is now in the true state, this line is printed and so the following lines, up to the line which starts with the tag `# sent_id = 2.`

Here the `$f` switches to the false state again: `$f = 0 if /sent_id/;` and the next statement, `print "$_" if $f` is not executed. While still on the same line, the tag `# sent_id = 2` is matched again and turns `$f` into the true state: `$f = 1 if /sent_id/;`

Now the `while` loop moves to the next line: `"# text = L’année a été généreuse en innovations prometteuses. ..."` Since `$f` is now in the true state, this line and the following ones (up the tag `# sent_id = 3`) are printed.

Answer (score 0):

Please investigate the following solution for compliance with your task

- define local *end of the record* on empty line
- read records from `<>` in `map` loop
- utilize regex to capture only what you interested in
- store result in `@blocks` array
- show `@blocks` elements with `say` (optional)

NOTE: run as `./script.pl datafile`

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my @blocks;

{
    local $/ = "\n\n";
    @blocks = map { /(# sent_id = .*)/s } <>;
}

say for @blocks;
```